# How to change OpenShift console URL and API URL

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, redhat, openshift-origin, okd

My company runs OpenShift v3.10 cluster consisting of 3 masters and 4 nodes. We would like to change URL of the OpenShift API and also the URL of the OpenShift web console. Which steps we need to take to successfully do so?

We have already tried to update the o`penshift_master_cluster_hostname` and `openshift_master_cluster_public_hostname` variables to new DNS names, which resolve our F5 virtual hosts which load balances the traffic between our masters, and then started the upgrade Ansible playbook, but the upgrade fails. We have also tried to run the Ansible playbook which redeploys the cluster certificates, but after that step the OpenShift nodes status changes to `NotReady`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have solved this issue. What we had to do is to change the URL-s defined in the variables in the inventory file and then we executed the ANSIBLE playbook to update master configuration. The process of running that playbook is describe in the official [documentation](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.10/install_config/master_node_configuration.html).

After that we also had to update the OpenShift Web Console configuration map with new URL-s and then scale down and scale up the web-console deployment. The process on how to update the configuration of the web-console is described [here](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.10/install_config/web_console_customization.html).