# OKD openshift-ansible: Updating 'openshift_master_cluster_public_hostname' and certificate

Tags: ansible, openshift, okd

I have Openshift deployed and working fine, but now am putting a DNS record and a valid certificate in front of it. I haven't had any luck and haven't found any documentation on doing this.

My strategy just to update the hostname was to `sed` the existing public hostname with the new one in all files in the master/node configurations, but that didn't seem to work.

Is there a specific playbook/inventory fields I need to use/update in order to update this easily from the Ansible master?

---

UPDATE: I ran the 'openshift-master/redeploy-certificates.yaml' after I updated the inventory file with the following:

```
openshift_master_overwrite_named_certificates=true
openshift_master_cluster_public_hostname=new-public-hostname.com
```

Afterwards I checked the certs on the master node and they seemed to have added a new SAN to the `master.server.crt` and `etcd.server.crt`. However, when I go to the new hostname, it still redirects me to the old hostname. Is there another playbook I'm missing to update that in the system?

Comment: Use `curl -i https://newhostname` and verify that you are actually being redirected. Some browsers remember too much.

Answer (score 0):

The redirection might be caused by the web console service that probably is not configured and uses the old masterURL.

Check this previous thread https://stackoverflow.com/a/54399071/2802150 as it addresses the same problem.